# CriteriaBuilder - inverted LIKE

Tags: hibernate, criteria-api

Using CriteriaBuilder, I want to build a LIKE-Predicate, which corresponds to the following SQL:

```
 SELECT e.* FROM entity e WHERE 'aStringValue' LIKE e.aProperty || '%'
```

(Oracle SQL - the `||`-Operator does concatenation)

In other words, I have to search a Table `e` containing a Field `aProperty` where short forms of different varchar-values are stored, for a specific value `aStringValue`.

How can one achive this using CriteriaBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but this should do what you want:

```
cb.like(cb.literal("aStringValue"), 
        cb.concat(myEntity.get(MyEntity_.aProperty), "%"));
```